# I want to show saved data in redux saga store when user select the page again

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

This is my component code. This will get repot from API and populate in antd table. When I go to another page and come back it shows an empty page. I want old data until it replaces by another query.

```
function onChange(value, dateString) {
  setSelectedDates(dateString);
  dispatch(
    getAdminPerformance({
      reportType,
      dates: dateString,
    })
  );
}


const ReportAdminAuditLogs = React.memo(() => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState([]);
  const [reportType] = useState("performed-action");
  const { performedActionList, totalCount } = useSelector(
    ({ adminPerformance }) => adminPerformance
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `redux-persist` it will help you to save your redux state in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

you can find it from this [Link](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)